# Top menu show only subcategories of a specific category

Tags: menu, navigation

These are my categories :

```
Root category
---> Shoes
---- ---> Red    shoes
---- ---> Green  shoes
---- ---> Yellow shoes
---> Shirts
---- ---> Black shirts
---- ---> White shirts
---- ---> Blue  shirts
```

and my top menu would be like:

`-Shoes`         `-Shirts`

But I only want to show my shoes in the top menu, Like this :

`-Red shoes`    `-Green shoes`    `-Yellow shoes`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The categories are added in the top menu using this method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer::addCatalogToTopmenuItems`.
buy default the method looks like this:

```
public function addCatalogToTopmenuItems(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $this->_addCategoriesToMenu(Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getStoreCategories(), $observer->getMenu());
}
```

This means that it adds to the top menu the result of `Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getStoreCategories()` recursively.
All you need to do is to rewrite this method and make it show only the child categories you need.

Something like this. Let's say that your `shoes` category id is 5.

```
public function addCatalogToTopmenuItems(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $parent = 5;
    $recursionLevel  = max(0, (int) Mage::app()->getStore()->getConfig('catalog/navigation/max_depth') - 1) //subtract 1 from the set recursion level because we skip a level;
    $categories= Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($parent, $recursionLevel, false, false, true);
    $this->_addCategoriesToMenu($categories, $observer->getMenu());
}
```

I haven't tested it, but I think the idea is there.

Comment: It didn't change anything.

Comment: wait...I think I got you question wrong. You mean you want to see in the menu only `-Red shoes  -Green shoes  -Yellow shoes` or the parent category `shoes` also?

Comment: no, not parent category, just **subcategories** of a specific category ( Shoes )

Comment: @AlirezaFallah. Then it means I got it right. My answer should help you achieve what you need.

Comment: I put a `die()` on the first line o that function in  `Catalog/Model/Observer.php` , It didn't die.

Comment: You should work with the cache off. Also try it first on the default theme. Maybe your theme builds the menu differently.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. when I change the theme to default, it works fine, but some problems still there that I have to solve. maybe I get some help from you tomorrow :)